# osx python not found but python3 found

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am unable to find or locate python in osx. but python3 works. however my pip packages are all installed not sure how with pip and not pip3. Any idea how I can use my pip packages with python3 and not having to installed them again with pip3? I believe python3 was installed via brew

```
 % brew list
==> Formulae
autoconf    kubernetes-cli  mpdecimal   python@3.10 virtualenv
ca-certificates libidn2     openssl@1.1 readline    wget
gdbm        libunistring    pkg-config  six     xz
gettext     m4      pyenv       sqlite

==> Casks
mysqlworkbench      virtualbox
vagrant         visual-studio-code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which python3` to locate your python installation

If your packages were installed for a different version of Python, they are very likely not compatible with your current version of Python, especially if you were using Python 2 before and now using Python 3. If you want to try to keep all your current packages, use `pip freeze` to export your current list of installed packages, remove the version numbers, and reinstall them using the pip of the Python distribution of your choice.